# ¿Cómo agregar un valor al array de la propiedad hobby?

Tags: javascript, clase

Hice esto pero obtengo `undefined`.
El método `agregarHob` recibe un parámetro que se debe agregar al array del elemento hobby. Es solo eso pero me pide que siga escribiendo. Soy nuevo aquí y no se como funciona esto

```js
 class Persona {

 constructor(hobby){

 this.hobby= hobby;

}

 agregarHob(hobi) {
      return this.hobby.push(hobi);
  }

}  

 const yo = new Persona(["futbol", "musica" ]);
 console.log(yo.agregarHob("beber"))
```

Comment: Bienvenido a SOes te recomiendo que realices el [tour] para que sepas como funciona el sitio, también lee [¿Cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Recuerda incluir una breve descripción de tu problema en la pregunta para saber el contexto de la situación.

Comment: es `console.log()` sin tilde! y el `Const` va en minúsculas `cosnt`

Comment: Si. Lo escribí mal aquí.

Comment: lo ejecuté con todas las correcciones y no me aparece ningún `undefined`

Comment: Se agrega el valor al array?

Comment: Pues sip, edita tu pregunta corriendo los errores ortográficos y pondre un snippet

Comment: Listo ya corregi

Comment: Pero solo retorna la cantidad de string que hay en el array. Yo quiero que retorne el Array con sus strings

Comment: El método push siempre retornsra el índice del nuevo elemento, tendrías que retornar el array. La respuesta que te dieron es bueno

Comment: Me sirvió. Gracias

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que el método push no retorna el nuevo array con el valor agregado. En su lugar puedes intentar con el método **Array.concat**

```
class Persona {
  constructor(hobby){
    this.hobby= hobby;
  }

  agregarHob(hobi) {
    return this.hobby.concat(hobi);
  }
}  

const yo = new Persona(["futbol", "musica" ]);
console.log(yo.agregarHob("beber"))
```

Espero que te sirva. Saludos.